# Is it possible to use the linear velocity from an optical flow sensors along with IMU data (sensor fusion) in the ekf_localization package? How?

Tags: navigation, sensor-fusion, extended-kalman-filter, robot-pose-ekf, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I am using the px4flow optical flow camera module with pixhawk.
It outputs linear velocity, i would like to use this somehow in the extended kalman filter in ros.
The inputs to the robot_pose_ekf are odometry for 2d position, 3d orientation and 6d visual odometry for both 3d position and 3d orientation.

Is it possible to use this package for linear velocity also, or would i have to integrate the data and use the position instead?
And ofcourse, if it is possible, how would i got about doing this?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218586/is-it-possible-to-use-the-linear-velocity-from-an-optical-flow-sensors-along-with-imu-data-(sensor-fusion)-in-the-ekf_localization-package?-if-so,-how?/) by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2015-10-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out. There also is a kalman filter package that, called [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization), that allows you to add any number of sensors that you would like.
It neither restricts your odometry input to 2D (wheel odometry).
It also gives you the choice between an extended kalman filter or an unscented kalman filter.

---

Originally posted by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) with karma: 92 on 2015-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elyazid](https://answers.ros.org/users/76198/elyazid/) on 2021-06-17**:
Hi,
I'm working on the same project, i am using the px4flow optical flow camera, and i want to use optical flow data in the extended Kalman filter in ROS.
could you please explain how did you use the optical flow data in robot_localisation